# Glibc vs GCC vs binutils compatibility

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc, binutils

Is there a sort of official documentation about version compatibility between binutils, glibc and GCC? I found [this matrix](http://wiki.osdev.org/Cross-Compiler_Successful_Builds) for binutils vs GCC version compatibility. It would be good to have something like this for GCC vs glibc as well.

The point I'm asking this for is that I need to know if I can build, say, cross GCC 4.9.2 with "embedded" glibc 2.2.4 to be able to support quite old targets like CentOS 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

it's extremely unlikely you'll be able to build such an old version of glibc with such a new version of gcc.  glibc documents the min required version of binutils & gcc in its [INSTALL file](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=INSTALL;hb=glibc-2.23).

glibc-2.23 states:

```
Recommended Tools for Compilation
GCC 4.7 or newer
GNU 'binutils' 2.22 or later
```

typically if you want to go newer than those, glibc will generally work with the version of gcc that was in development at the time of the release.  e.g. glibc-2.23 was released 18 Feb 2016 and gcc-6 was under development at that time, so glibc-2.23 will work with gcc-4.7 through gcc-6.

so find the [version of gcc](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/) you want, then find its release date, then look at the [glibc releases](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/glibc/) from around the same time.

all that said, using an old version of glibc is a terrible idea.  it will be full of known security vulnerabilities (include remotely exploitable ones).  the latest glibc-2.23 release for example fixed [CVE-2015-7547](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18665) which affects any application doing DNS network resolution and affects versions starting with glibc-2.9.  remember: this is not the only bug lurking.

Comment: Why would you by unable to *build* an older version of glibc with a much newer version of gcc? (That is not to say that the much newer version of gcc will be able to *use* said old version of glibc internally, but if I wanted to build an executable for CentOS 5, as the OP states, shouldn't I be able to use even say, GCC 9, checkout the source for glibc 2.22 and build glibc 2.22.
Then to build app for CentOS 5, I would compile source with GCC 9, and applicably old `-std=c99`, and then manually link using `LDFLAGS=-nostdlib`, and `LDLIBS=-l:libc.so.2.2.2`?

Comment: there have been many known issues whereby a newer gcc miscompiles an older glibc because glibc relies on behavior that has changed (sometimes on purpose, sometimes by incidentally).  it can either fail to compile entirely, or it'll compile & then simply crash when executed.  the further apart the releases, the more likely this is to happen.

Answer (score 1):

When building a cross-compiler there are at least two, and sometimes three, platform types to consider:

*Platform A* is used to *BUILD* a cross compiler **HOSTED** on **Platform B** which `TARGETS` binaries for embedded `Platform C`. I used the words *BUILD*, **HOSTED**, and `TARGETS` intentionally, as those are the options passed to configure when building a cross-GCC.

---

- *BUILD PLATFORM*: Platform of machine which will create the cross-GCC
- **HOST PLATFORM**: Platform of machine which will use the cross-GCC to create binaries
- `TARGET PLATFORM`: Platform of machine which will
  run the binaries created by the cross-GCC

---

Consider the following (Canadian Cross Config, *BUILD* != **HOST** platform):
A 32-bit x86 Windows PC running the mingw32 toolchain will be used to compile a cross-GCC. This cross-GCC will be used on 64-bit x86 Linux computers. The binaries created by the cross-GCC should run on a 32-bit PowerPC single-board-computer running LynxOS 178 RtOS (Realtime Operating System).

In the above scenario, our platforms are as follows:
*BUILD*: i686-w32-mingw32
**HOST**: x86_64-linux-gnu
`TARGET`: powerpc-lynx-lynxos178

However, this is not the typical configuration. Most often *BUILD PLATFORM* and **HOST PLATFORM** are the same.

---

A more typical scenario (Regular Cross Config, *BUILD* == **HOST** platform):
A 64-bit x86 Linux server will be used to compile a cross-GCC. This cross-GCC will also be used on 64-bit x86 Linux computers. The binaries created by the cross-GCC should run on a 32-bit PowerPC single-board-computer running LynxOS 178 RtOS (Realtime Operating System).

In the above scenario, our platforms are as follows:
*BUILD*: x86_64-linux-gnu
**HOST**: x86_64-linux-gnu
`TARGET`: powerpc-lynx-lynxos178

---

When building the cross-GCC (assuming we are building a Regular Cross Config, where *BUILD* == **HOST** Platform), native versions of GNU BinUtils, GCC, glibc, and libstdc++ (among other libraries) will be required to actually compile the cross-GCC. It is less about specific versions of each component, and more about whether each component supports  the specific language features required to compile GCC-4.9.2 (note: just because GCC-4.9.2 implements language feature X, does not mean that language feature X must be supported by the version of GCC used to compile GCC-4.9.2. In the same way, just because glibc-X.X.X implements library feature Y, does not mean that the version of GCC used to compile glibc-X.X.X must have been linked against a glibc that implements feature Y.

---

In your case, you should simply build your cross-GCC 4.9.2 (or if you are not cross compiling, i.e. you are compiling for CentOS 5 on Linux, build native GCC 4.9.2), and then when you link your executable for CentOS 5, explicitly link glibc v2.2.4 using `-l:libc.so.2.2.4`. You also probably will need to define `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` when you compile, as I highly doubt glibc 2.2.4 supports the `C 2011` standard.