# How to create / general steps to create SDK for Linux Kernel and given cpu architecture?

Tags: linux-kernel, sdk, kernel, intel-xdk

How to cross compile my current code running on

```
Linux kernel 5.0.0-37 
architecture x86_64,
Intel core i7-8850H CPU.
```

onto

```
Architecture i686
Model name: Inte Atom CPU E3845 @ 1.91 Ghz
Linux Kernel 4.9.65
```

After a bit of googling, understood that i need to create SDK of the desired platform. But the now the question is how to create the SDK ? what are the general steps people follow to create SDK? Is there any general tutorial that i could follow to get some understanding of the step for creation of SDK.

I see that some people writing bash scripts to create an SDK. But in my case, i have access to the system and can SSH into it. Is it possible to create SDK of the system while being inside it, like cloning all the folders or by installing some kind of software to create SDK etc...

I am completely new to these kind of tasks and any lead is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of browsing and reading several article. I found that these information is absolutely necessary to build an SDK...

```
target architecture: eg AMD-32 bit/64 bit (i386 / i686 / x86_64), ARM , etc
binutils :
Kernel :
GCC :
GLIBC:
```

These are the few articles and open source software that are able to achieve the task

[How to build a gcc cross compiler](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/)

[crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.github.io/)

[building-ubuntu-rootfs-for-arm](https://gnu-linux.org/building-ubuntu-rootfs-for-arm.html)

[glibc-vs-gcc-vs-binutils-compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873558/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873558/glibc-vs-gcc-vs-binutils-compatibility)

[lfs-museum](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/)